# Running Wine applications from different terminal paths yield different results?

Tags: command-line, wine, paths

I'm going to use the game "cosmoteer" as an example (as it's free), but I ran into this with others.

**Issue:**
If I run:

```
cd /path/to/executable/
wine exec.exe
```

The program runs.

But if I do:

```
wine /path/to/executable/exec.exe
```

The program / application changes the "working directory" (I think it's called like this) and fails to execute.
Do you guys know what is the issue here? I can't find a solution on the internet that resembles this one. Or at least one that has a solution, most of them are empty threads with no answer.

Comment: Whoever wrote the app probably made some silly assumptions.

Comment: I don't understand the aim of your question. You already know a simple way to get the application to run. What else would you like to to know or achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that wine has an special command for this.
You must issue the

```
wine start /d <path>
```

where `<path>` is the directory to start in.

https://wiki.winehq.org/Start

Answer (score 1):

The wine executable doesn't change directory to the path of the executable that you're passing it.  That's necessary otherwise you wouldn't be able to for example run wine /path/to/7-zip and have it operate on the current directory... it would always annoyingly and uselessly operate on the 7-zip directory!

Frequently with windows apps there are various dependencies in the folder with the executable, so it's good to cd there before running it.  If you don't want to lose your current directory you can always:

```
pushd /path/to/executable/
wine exec.exe;
popd
```

Hope that helps.

PS I'd love to know what steps you took and what luck you have getting cosmoteer to run.  My buddy is temporarily infatuated with this game and I'd like to poke around it but I can't get the installer to run.  It just tells me that my system doesn't meet the dotnet framework requirements, but I used playonlinux to install the latest (4.5) into the bottle ahead of the game...

Comment: Alternatively use a subshell: `( cd <PATH> && exec wine <EXE> )`

Comment: Hey wil, I was able to run it on my linux PC, I'm not sure what kind of witchcraft I did but even Walt (The game developer) said that I was the first guy he knew who was able to run the game on Wine.
If you need to know something else please let me know I'll be glad to answer, and maybe you can discover what makes my PC so special lol.